# Is a thank you note appropriate for the end of my internship?

Tags: professionalism, internship

I'm nearing the end of my summer internship, and I've read that writing thank-you notes is a good way to maintain relationships, and just end the internship on a positive note in general.

Is this something that I should do, or will it be cheesy? Is a thank-you email too impersonal? I don't even know what a thank-you note consist of...do I go full on with a card and envelope, or something smaller?

I'd like to hear some insight from people with experience in this.

Comment: Does this answer what you are looking for? http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/25915/2322

Comment: It's really, completely, totally, trivially up to you. What's "cheesy" to one person could be poetry to another, or genius, or basic manners. When in doubt, do it in person.

Comment: Aged 14 I did "work experience", which is what the UK calls a two-week internship for children, at a solicitor's office. They had a thank-you letter from a pupil at my school who'd done the same thing there the previous year, pinned on a noticeboard on the wall. So yeah, these things may be greatly appreciated. Downside was, I couldn't use the form letter that the school gave us in our work experience advice booklet, because they'd already got one...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this something that I should do, or will it be cheesy? Is a
>   thank-you email too impersonal? I don't even know what a thank-you
>   note consist of...do I go full on with a card and envelope, or
>   something smaller?

**It won't be cheesy at all, and if sincere, will be remembered and appreciated.**

Over the years, I hired many interns. On their final week, I took them out to lunch to talk about their experiences, ask them for suggestions on what I could do better for future interns, and to thank them for their hard work. Usually, they thanked me in person as well.

Some of the interns sent a follow-up letter thanking me for the opportunity, mentioning how much they had learned, and hinting that they would be amenable to a full-time job once they graduated. On several of those occasions, I took the up on the offer and did hire them when they became available.

The specific format wasn't very important - sometimes it was a thank you card, other times a handwritten letter, sometimes just an email. Far more important was the contents. A sincere thank you goes a long way.